# Некорректно выводится значение поля класса

Tags: php, ооп

пытаюсь вывести значение поля "surname" класса "User", вместо этого выводится значение другого поля. Не могу понять, что происходит. Вместо необходимого "JohnNone" выводится "JohnJohn".

```
<?php
      class User{
        public $name;
        public $surname = "None";
        private $email;
        private $ligin;
        private $pass;
      }

      $admin = new User();
      $admin->$name = "John";
      echo $admin->$name;
      echo $admin->$surname;
    ?>
```

Comment: Не следует плюсовать вопросы, вызванные банальной опечаткой

Comment: @Ипатьев, может, у меня уже взгляд замылился, но я, честно слово, не вижу опечатки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Банальная опечатка, вот правильный вариант:

```
class User{
    public $name;
    public $surname = "None";
    private $email;
    private $login;
    private $pass;
  }

  $admin = new User();
  $admin->name = "John";
  echo $admin->name;
  echo $admin->surname;
```

Comment: Черт...В учебном материале указано, что  $ должен быть *facepalm*

Comment: Если уж расстарались написать целый ответ, то потрудитесь ответить на вопрос, почему имя все равно выводится, и при этом два раза